# Odd spacing on CSS dropdown menu in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've inherited a site and I'm changing the navigation. On my page I'm using a CSS drop down (or drop 'up' in my case) that is showing some unusual spacing between the nested list items of the drop down list. Additionally, if I try to hover to the drop down items the list disappears when the mouse hits the blank space between the elements.

[image: Aberrant spacing on items]

It looks fine on Chrome, Safari and FF. IE8 seems to be the problem... I know I've got to be staring right at the error and not seeing it. Any help is appreciated.

My (relevant) HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="1000" height="32">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="10" height="32"><img src="images/divider1.gif" alt="" width="10" height="32" border="0"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="980" height="32">
    <ul id="midnav">

      <!-- Accommodations -->
      <li onmouseover="acco.src='images/accommodations-on.gif'" onmouseout="acco.src='images/accommodations-off.gif'">
        <a href="accommodations/" class="pointer"><img src="images/accommodations-off.gif" alt="Accommodations" width="136" height="32" border="0" id="acco" name="acco"></a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="images/accom_top_strip.png" width="136" height="24" border="0">
            <a href="accommodations/guest-services.cfm" onmouseover="accom_gs.src='images/accom_guest_services_on.png'" onmouseout="accom_gs.src='images/accom_guest_services_off.png'" class="pointer"><img src="images/accom_guest_services_off.png" alt="Guest Services" width="136" height="24" border="0" id="accom_gs" name="accom_gs"></a>
                    </li>
          <li>
            <a href="luxury-townhomes.cfm" onmouseover="accom_lth.src='images/luxury_townhomes_on.png'" onmouseout="accom_lth.src='images/luxury_townhomes_off.png'" class="pointer"><img src="images/luxury_townhomes_off.png" alt="Luxury Townhomes" width="136" height="24" border="0" id="accom_lth" name="accom_lth"></a>
                    </li>
          <li>
            <a href="three-bedroom-condo.cfm" onmouseover="accom_3bc.src='images/three_bed_condo_on.png'" onmouseout="accom_3bc.src='images/three_bed_condo_off.png'" class="pointer"><img src="images/three_bed_condo_off.png" alt="Three Bedroom Condo" width="136" height="24" border="0" id="accom_3bc" name="accom_3bc"></a>
                    </li>
          <li>
            <a href="two-bedroom-condo.cfm" onmouseover="accom_2bc.src='images/three_bed_condo_on.png'" onmouseout="accom_2bc.src='images/two_bed_condo_off.png'" class="pointer"><img src="images/two_bed_condo_off.png" alt="Two Bedroom Condo" width="136" height="24" border="0" id="accom_2bc" name="accom_2bc"></a>
                    </li>
          <li>
            <a href="one-bedroom-condo.cfm" onmouseover="accom_1bc.src='images/one_bed_condo_on.png'" onmouseout="accom_1bc.src='images/one_bed_condo_off.png'" class="pointer"><img src="images/one_bed_condo_off.png" alt="One Bedroom Condo" width="136" height="24" border="0" id="accom_1bc" name="accom_1bc"></a>
                    </li>
          <li>
            <a href="studio.cfm" onmouseover="accom_studio.src='images/studio_on.png'" onmouseout="accom_studio.src='images/studio_off.png'" class="pointer"><img src="images/studio_off.png" alt="Studio" width="136" height="24" border="0" id="accom_studio" name="accom_studio"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
 </td>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="10" height="32"><img src="images/divider2.gif" alt="" width="10" height="32" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
/* Main CSS */

ul {
    margin-top:13px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 50px;  
  }
li{
    list-style-image: url(../images/bullet.gif);
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #9a631b; 
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

/* Mid Page Navigation */

ul#midnav {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:32px;
    width:980px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10000;
    list-style:none;
    font-size:0;    
}
ul#midnav li {
    list-style-image:none;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:32px;
}
ul#midnav li a {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul#midnav li ul {
    list-style:none;
    display:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:0;
}
ul#midnav li:hover ul, ul#midnav li.hover ul {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:10001;
}
ul#midnav li:hover li, #midnav li.hover li {
    list-style-image:none;
    float:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:auto;
    line-height:normal;
    height:auto;
}
ul#midnav li:hover li a, #midnav li.hover li a {
    line-height:none;
}
```

And a little JS to make the hover work in IE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul#midnav li').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).addClass("hover");
        },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
        }
     );
```

Comment: This sounds familiar. Maybe this helps? http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Sorry, but there is not enough here to be able to help without guessing. Your code contains links to images that don't exist so it is difficult to make a working example. Could you either make a working example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or provide a link to the site that has the problem?

Comment: The most important rule of list-based menus: other than positioning/floats, use display:block and put all styling on the A-tag, not the LI.

Comment: After reviewing the link posted in the above comments, I removed the spaces in my code between the `</li><li>` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

till you are using `table` to build website, its a old method. Use `DIV` for better look.